# Installed SQL Server 2008 - SQL Server agent is disabled - How to fix this?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I think my Microsoft SQL Server database is inaccessible because the SQL server agent is disabled and cannot be started. How can I fix this problem?

```
For SQL Server agent
State - stopped running
Start mode - Other(Boot,System,Disabled or unknown)
Log On As - NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

For SQL Server Browser
State - running
Start mode - auto
Log On As - NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE.

For SQL Server agent
State - running
Start mode - auto
Log On As - LocalSystem
```

Comment: for adding images use a hosting like tinypic.url and put the url using the tag for that

Comment: @ElVieejo -  can you help me with this issue ? The upload to tiny pic failed. I will type the columns manually -
For SQL Server agent -
State - stopped running, Start mode - Other(Boot,System,Disabled or unknown), Log On As - NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE.

For SQL Server Browser -
State - running, Start mode - auto, Log On As - NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE.

For SQL Server agent -
State - running, Start mode - auto, Log On As - LocalSystem

Comment: I'm not sure if I can help you with this :/. And please, edit your question, and add that, not in the comments !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it is disabled, go to Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Services, and look for the SQL Server Agent. Right-click, and select "Properties." From the "Startup Type" dropdown, change from "Disabled" to "Automatic".

**Clarification from comments:** The "SQL Server Agent" service must be differentiated from the "SQL Server" *database* process. The former runs jobs, performs monitoring tasks, things of that nature, but it alone should not prevent "SQL Server" from running or allowing connections. If you note the SQL Server service is running (*not* the "Sql Server Agent"), and cannot connect to it, something else is likely at hand, such as a firewall, or is misconfigured in some way that is preventing connections.

If you note that the SQL Server service is not running, and will not start, there is a broader configuration issue you should research in the event logs.

Comment: I set it to auto and then restarted my system. It does not work. Btw, what prompted you to suggest that ?

Comment: Just hoping to answer your original question re a service being disabled. That's just the standard way to change the startup type of a Windows service. I'd check the system/application event logs for further detail about why the service would not start. That said, typically, the Agent's presence is not going to prevent access to SQL Server - the Agent is responsible for scheduled jobs, and monitoring. If "SQL Server" is started, you should be able to access it. Check for possible firewall restrictions...you might also specify how you're trying to access it.

Comment: @READER - Answer does NOT work for me. But, i need the points.
thanks.

Comment: If you're still not able to connect, relay what tool you're connecting with, and the specific error you receive, and I'll be glad to try to help further...

Comment: No problem david w. It works now. I did a reinstall and then created another post which solved the problem nicely - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326724/impossible-to-connect-to-sql-server-2008

Comment: Okay, great! Glad it all worked out for you. Would have been glad to help with the firewall had you needed it :) Congrats on getting it solved.